# How can I implement google map tile cache in Android?

Tags: android, google-maps

Is it possible to cache google map tiles for specific region in Android using google maps SDK?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Android Map SDK has no api for that.

Answer (score 0):

I dont think that is possible Google Maps Library for Android.
You could cache tiles using [Static Maps APIs](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/staticmaps/) which return each tile as a png image.

Comment: It is not allowed by ToS of Google Maps.